# Access $scope in directive

Tags: angularjs

I am new to angularJS, so need some inputs.
I am trying to access a $scope variable in one of the directies.I have set the $scope value in controller.
Below is the hierarchy of the flow.
Order.js has $scope variable defined.

```
   $scope.test = true;
```

Order.html calls another html

```
 <cra-violations-table
       violations="order.violations"
       on-assign-success="onAssignSuccess" 
       order-status="order.statusCd" 
       edit-allowed="order.editAllowed"/>
```

and `cra-violations-table.html` calls a directive

```
<searchpersonnelfilterctrl 
      search-ctrl="assignModify"/>
```

searchpersonnelfilterctrl is defined in `filtercomponent.js`
And I am trying to access the variable here in `filtercomponent.js`.

```
.directive('searchpersonnelfilterctrl', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'AEC',
        scope: {
            class: '=class',
            title: '=title',
            searchCtrl: '=searchCtrl',
            placeholder: '=placeholder',
            typeahead: '@',
            typeaheadTemplateUrl: '@?'
        },
        templateUrl: 'includes/filter-component-search.html',

        compile: function(element, attrs) {
            // Set default values
            attrs.$set("test", "$parent.test");
          }
```

But it is undefined.
Can somebody please help me with that.
Thanks

Comment: Please share the relevant parts of directive's code as well.

Comment: why dont you pass test variable as binding to the directive ?
'<' for one-way, '=' for 2-awy

Comment: @PanosK yes I can do that but the imapct after changing filtercomponent.html is too much..We don't want to touch that..

Comment: you can not get scope in compile, only in link